# ElasticSearch null_pointer_exception when trying to access any object type of field using ctx._source

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a index mapping like below

```
PUT /customer-index
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
        "customers.id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "customers.name": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false
      },
      "customers.company": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To this index, I have added two documents

```
PUT /customer-index/_doc/1
{
  "customers.company" : "google",
  "customers.id" : 1,
  "customers.name" : "adams"
}

PUT /customer-index/_doc/2
{
  "customers.company" : "apple",
  "customers.id" : 2,
  "customers.name" : "james"
}
```

Now I am trying to use `update by query` to update company to samsung where id is 2 . In real scenario, I have to update multiple docs in multiple indexes where id matches, that is why I am using `update by query`. But for simplicity, I have posted like this

```
POST /customer-index/_update_by_query
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.customers.company = params.company",
    "lang": "painless",
    "params": {
      "company": "samsung"
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "customers.id": 2
    }
  }
}
```

But it is always throwing null_pointer_exception

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "ctx._source.customers.company = params.company",
          "                     ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "ctx._source.customers.company = params.company",
        "lang": "painless",
        "position": {
          "offset": 21,
          "start": 0,
          "end": 46
        }
      }
    ],
    "type": "script_exception",
    "reason": "runtime error",
    "script_stack": [
      "ctx._source.customers.company = params.company",
      "                     ^---- HERE"
    ],
    "script": "ctx._source.customers.company = params.company",
    "lang": "painless",
    "position": {
      "offset": 21,
      "start": 0,
      "end": 46
    },
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "null_pointer_exception",
      "reason": "Cannot invoke \"Object.getClass()\" because \"callArgs[0]\" is null"
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Adding a null check can avoid this error but my question is why I am getting null_pointer_exception when I have the document present in the index.
I have checked at lot of places but still no luck. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `customers` is not an object type, you need to access it like this:

```
ctx._source['customers.company']
```

Your query would work if you have declared your `customers` field like this:

```
PUT /customer-index
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "customers": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "customers.name": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          },
          "customers.company": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dig a little deeper and found out below things. I will try to explain it with an example.
Let's create 2 indexes, `customer-index-10` and `customer-index-20`.

```
PUT /customer-index-10
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "customers": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "id": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          },
          "company": {
            "type": "text",
            "norms": false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
PUT /customer-index-20
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "customers.id": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "customers.name": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false
      },
      "customers.company": {
        "type": "text",
        "norms": false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you invoke the _mapping API on both the indexes, it will return the same result which means in both the cases customer will be treated as type object. But the way update by query works in both the indexes that is different.

for index `/customer-index-10`, a script like this will work

`"source" : "ctx._source.customers.name = 'updated name'"`

But for index `/customer-index-20`, the above script will throw Null Pointer Exception and below script will work

`"source" : "ctx._source['customers.name'] = 'updated name'"`

Comment: This is because the `subobjects` property is true by default: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/subobjects.html